# How to change a checkbox value onclick a text in mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a checkbox and your name. this is the code:

```
  <div class="type_wine">
      <div class="check_type">@Html.CheckBox(color, check, new { @class = "wine" })</div>                                            
      <div id="type_text" onclick="checkByName('@color')">  color  </div>
  </div>
```

I must to do the same then I clicked the text and then I click on check box, then I do a click in the checkbox all is ok, but I have a problem then I clicked the text, because the checkbox state is not changed can sameone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
<div class="type_wine">
    <label>
        <div class="check_type">@Html.CheckBox(color, check, new { @class = "wine" }</div>
        <div id="type_text">
            color
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but will be a problem if I have a list of checkboxes